# Adding parameter to link, then redirect results in amp; in $_GET

Tags: jquery

How do I correctly add a parameter to a link with jquery? I've now read various threads here about that, but I can't get it to work right.

In detail, if the user clicks a certain link on click I want to get the value of an input, afterwards add it to the clicked link and redirect the user with the new url with the added parameter.

Everything works just fine, but when I dump the $_GET with Php on the target URL I always end up with amp;parameter_name instead of parameter_name. What I do:

```
$('#add-item-wishlist').bind('click', function(e) {
// get quantity from input
var current_qty = $('.inp-qty').val();

//redirect user
e.preventDefault();
window.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + '&qty=' + current_qty;

});
```

&qty always results in amp;qty if I dump with php, so does the check inside the php script fail.

// edit
may I mention that i use this snippet in en enviroment with Smarty Template Engine?

---

#### Fixed

I fixed it by moving the code to the HTML head, removing it from the Smart html template file. Seems smarty messed it up in some way.

Comment: try to alert before window.location.href to verify current_qty has some value  alert( $(this).attr("href") + '&qty=' + current_qty);

Comment: so if i alert this i end up with:

wish_list.php?addWishlist=yes&products_id=1&amp;qty=1

Comment: You can keep JavaScript code in separate file and include it using <script src="path/to javascript/file"></script>.

Comment: try to var_dump on php page to list what parameters are coming into $_Get array var_dump($_GET);

Answer (score 0):

try using [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

```
window.location.href = encodeURI($(this).attr("href") + '&qty=' + current_qty);
```

so to properly encode the `&` character

Comment: nope still the same problem. if i alert it with encodeURI i end up with: wish_list.php?addWishlist=yes&products_id=1&amp;qty=1

Answer (score 0):

I use a function that redirects the user like this:

```
function reloadPageAfterSomeAction(value_1, value_2) {
    self.location='somePageIHaveAndRedirectTo.php?value_1=' + value_1 + '&value_2=' + value_2;
}
```

Notice that you're supposed to begin with `?` after the "page-name" and a `&` between each value you're passing, as such:

```
http://www.mypage.com/index.html?value_1=123&value_2=456&value_3=789
```

Comment: the link the onclick is bind on has always to parameters, first starting with ? - second with & . I want to add it as a third parameter.

Comment: what exactly do you want to pass as a third parameter?

Comment: i fixed it by moving the code to the html <head> removing it from the smarty template file. seems smarty was the one to mess it up.

Comment: smarty is probably encoded in a different way. you can encode it by open it in notepad++ and click on the "Encoding" tab and choose the one that suits you

Comment: I did this. The file holding the HTML head had the same encoding as the smarty files. Even the Charset in the HTML head was the same. Maybe I should check what encoding the Apache serves...